# A question about the minimal polynomial of a transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

My Linear Algebra textbook states:

> Say the minimal polynomial of the transformation $T$ is $m(x)=p_1(x)^{e_1}p_2(x)^{e_2}\cdots p_s(x)^{e_s}$. Then $$n(p_i(T))^{e_1}$$, which is the null space associated with the transformation $n(p_i(T))^{e_1}$, is $T$-invariant.

Shouldn't $n(p_i(T))^{y}$ be $T$-invariant for all $1\leq y\leq e_i$, where $y\in\Bbb{N}$?

Reason: Take $v\in n(p_1(T))$. The minimial polynomial $m(x)$ can be written as $p_1(x)^{e_1-1}p_2(x)^{e_2}\cdots p_s(x)^{e_s}p_1(x)$. For any vector $v\in n(p_1(T))$, we can see that $m(T) (v)=0$. This is true for all powers of $p_i(T)^{e_1}$

Thanks.

Comment: Could someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. Note that your textbook does not state that the null spaces of the other powers are not invariant. Also note that the following more general statement holds.  Let $f\in K[X]$ be any polynomial over the field $K$, which should be the same field as the one over which you're considering $V$. I claim that the null space of $f(T)$, $T$ being a linear map $V\to V$, is $T$-invariant.

To see this, write $f=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k$ and let $v \in \ker(f(T))$. Then we have
$$f(T)(Tv)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k T^k (Tv) = T \sum_{k=0}^n a_k T^k v = T (0) = 0.$$

So the null space (or "kernel", $\ker$ for short) of any polynomial in $T$ is an invariant subspace (if you are unsure that this is really a subspace, you should go ahead and try to prove this yourself).